# Going-up theorem: isn't it an obvious corollary of Theorem 5.10 (Atiyah)?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-extensions

I am reading Atiyah-MacDonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*. Theorem 5.10 states the following:

> Let $A\subset B$ be rings, $B$ integral over $A$, and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Then there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $B$ such that $\mathfrak{q}\cap A=\mathfrak{p}$.

Then, the "Going-up" theorem is presented, which states the following:

> Let $A \subset B$ be rings, $B$ integral over $A$;
> let $\mathfrak{p}_1 \subset \dotsm \subset \mathfrak{p}_n$ be a chain of prime ideals of $A$ and
> $\mathfrak{q}_1 \subset \dotsm \subset \mathfrak{q}_m$ $(m < n)$ a chain of prime ideals of $B$ such that
> $\mathfrak{q}_i \cap A = \mathfrak{p}_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq m$).
> Then the chain $\mathfrak{q}_1 \subset \dotsm \subset \mathfrak{q}_m$ can be extended to a chain
> $\mathfrak{q}_1 \subset \dotsm \subset \mathfrak{q}_n$ such that $\mathfrak{q}_i \cap A = \mathfrak{p}_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Now; my problem is that I see the "Going-up" theorem as a trivial corollary of Theorem 5.10, and I think this must be because I am misunderstanding something. As I see it, if you have a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_i$ of $A$, then Theorem 5.10 grants the existance of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}_i$ of $B$ such that $\mathfrak{p}_i=A\cap \mathfrak{q}_i$. Moreover, doing this must preserve the inclusions, so you can easily find the chain of ideals $\mathfrak{q}_1 \subset \dotsm \subset \mathfrak{q}_n$. This is not, however, how Atiyah proves the result. Instead, he takes quotients of the form $A/\mathfrak{p_i}$ to find the ideal $\overline{\mathfrak{q}_{i+1}}$ of $B/\mathfrak{q}_i$ and then lift it back to $A$. I don't see why taking quotients is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mere fact that $q\cap A=p$ and $q'\cap A=p'$ and $p\subseteq p'$,

it does not logically follow that $q\subseteq q'$.

Comment: Yes tha't what I was thinking. Could you give me a counterexample? (It would have to be in a non-integral extension)

Comment: @kubo how about an element $r\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $r\times \overline{r}$ is a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$ greater than 2? The ideal generated by $r$ and that generated by $\overline{r}$ are not the same.